# Django model inheritance - only want instances of parent class in a query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say I have 2 models, one being the parent of another. How can I query all Places that aren't restaurants in Django? Place.objects.all() would include all restaurants right? I want to exclude the children from the results. Thank you!

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), you can check for the existence of the lowercase model name as an attribute:

```
places = Place.objects.all()
not_restaurants = [p for p in places if not hasattr(p, 'restaurant')]
```

Comment: You should use the database to filter it out like below

Answer (score 30):

Filter on Django's automatically-created `OneToOneField`.  If it `IS NULL`, this `Place` isn't a `Restaurant`.

```
non_restaurant_places = Place.objects.filter(restaurant__isnull=True)
```

Comment: I've heard filtering on subclass is bad for performance? I'm not sure exactly why but I just looked at the query for this and it looks like a pretty standard joins.

Comment: @SabrinaLeggett Queries that involve multiple tables are slower than queries that only involve one, but any kind of serious relational database application will involve joins. In this particular case, anything involving a Restaurant will involve two tables, since there's a one-to-one relationship with Place.

Comment: It's certainly a lot faster than post-filtering in Python like the accepted answer :D

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to have a `place_type` attribute on the `Place` model and then override `save` for `Place`, `Restaurant` and any other base class to set it properly when it's persisted. You could then query with `Place.objects.filter(place_type='PLACE')`. There could be other ways but they probably get very hairy very quickly.