# Can a parent class check if child class has such field?

Tags: django, inheritance, field, instance

I know that we can reference the parent's model from a child but is there a way to have it the other way?

sorry for any typo here.

Let's say if parent is

```
class Parent(Model):
    has_this = models.Charfield(max_length=128)

class Child(Parent):
    has_that = models.Boolean(default=True)

ch = Child.objects.filter(id=1).first()  // this will be instance of both Parent and Child as expected

pa = Parent.objects.filter(id=1).first() // is actually return the same as above but does not has the `Child` field `has_that`
```

What my question is, is there a way for `pa` to differential from a regular `Parent` if a query is called using `Parent.objects.filter`

I tried using `isisntance` but for `pa`, it's only true if it's `Parent` for `ch` it's true for both.  I cannot think of another way to differential this.

Also, `Parent` will not be abstract.

P.S. I thought of using `hasattr` but this would not work too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want [Django model inheritance - only want instances of parent class in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853850/django-model-inheritance-only-want-instances-of-parent-class-in-a-query)

Answer (score 2):

You can reference subclass properties by using the subclass as a field name:

```
Parent.objects.filter(child__isnull=True)
```

yields all bare `Parent` instances (that are not children).

This gets slightly unwieldy when you have multiple derived classes, though.

Obviously, you can also query for child fields via the parent class this way:

```
Parent.objects.filter(child__has_that=True)
```

yields instances of `Parent` that are also `Children` with `has_that` set to `True`.